# Deploying Web App from Visual Studio (2015+) to Microsoft Azure

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

When deploying a Web App + SQL to Microsoft Azure from PC, do I have to delete or comment out the connection string in my web config file for it to work correctly ?

Comment: Have you referenced to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)?

Comment: @TomSun; Thanks I did but didnt talk too much about connection strings as it relates to deploying the Web App with SQL Server. The only mention was to make sure that the connection string reference in the db context matches with the new created db connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I have to delete or comment out the connection string in my web config file for it to work correctly ?

If have Migrated you database and added the connection string in the Azure WebApp Applicaton setting. There is **no need** to delete or comment out the connection string in the Web config. It will override by [application appsetting or connection string](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) during runtime.

[image]